# Getting a list of all assets from filepicker - Migrate off of filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io

In the last year filepicker prices has ballooned from $15 a month to over $200 a month. I want to migrate off of filepicker to hosting on my own S3.

I need a list of all my assets on filepicker. How do I get that? Is there an easier method to migrate?

Comment: This seems like a Server-Fault problem to ask.

Comment: Try write to support@filepicker.io